# How do I stop Jawr processing some parts of CSS files?

Tags: java, css, jawr

I am currently using [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) to compress and bundle my css, javascript and image files.

[Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) is currently converting all of the url() links in my css files, regardless whether they are images or not.  For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NothingYouCouldSay';
    src: url('../fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.eot') format('eot');
    src: local("☺"), url('../fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.woff') format('woff'), url("../fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.otf") format("opentype"), url('../fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Jawr is converting all of the url() values, but then the resources cannot be found when the webserver is running, as I have configured the image servlet to listen only for *.png & *.jpg.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NothingYouCouldSay';
    src: url('../../../cb1130234589/resources/fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.eot') format('eot');
    src: local("☺"), url('../../../cb1130234589/resources/fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.woff') format('woff'), url("../../../cb1130234589/resources/fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.otf") format("opentype"), url('../../../cb1130234589/resources/fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../../cb1130234589/resources/fonts/NothingYouCouldSay.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If I add *.woff to the image servlet mapping, then the servlet complains that the mime type of the file is not understood.

Is there any way I can get Jawr to not process these particular particular URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after trying a few different ideas, I ended up writing my own custom post processor to handle this.  I reuse as much of the existing Jawr code as possible, which means it may be quite brittle if Jawr changes it's underlying code.

Anyway, here's what I wrote:

```
package com.bullethq.jawr.postprocessor;

import net.jawr.web.resource.FileNameUtils;
import net.jawr.web.resource.bundle.factory.util.PathNormalizer;
import net.jawr.web.resource.bundle.postprocess.BundleProcessingStatus;
import net.jawr.web.resource.bundle.postprocess.impl.CSSURLPathRewriterPostProcessor;
import net.jawr.web.resource.bundle.postprocess.impl.PostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomCssUrlPathRewriterPostProcessor extends CSSURLPathRewriterPostProcessor {

    public static final String CUSTOM_URL_PATH_REWRITER = "customcsspathrewriter";

    public CustomCssUrlPathRewriterPostProcessor() {
        super(CUSTOM_URL_PATH_REWRITER);
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    @Override
    protected PostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter createImageUrlRewriter(BundleProcessingStatus status) {
        return new CustomPostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter(status);
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    public class CustomPostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter extends PostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter {

        public CustomPostProcessorCssImageUrlRewriter(BundleProcessingStatus status) {
            super(status);
        }

        // ========================================================================
        // ========================================================================
        // ========================================================================
        @Override
        protected String getUrlPath(String match, String originalPath, String newCssPath) throws IOException {
            String url = match.substring(match.indexOf('(') + 1, match.lastIndexOf(')')).trim();

            // Remove any quotes if necessary.
            String quoteStr = "";
            if (url.startsWith("'") || url.startsWith("\"")) {
                quoteStr = String.valueOf(url.charAt(0));
                url = url.substring(1, url.length() - 1);
            }

            // We now check if the url ends in a known image file extension
            // If not, the url is ignored.
            if (FileNameUtils.hasImageExtension(url)) {
                return super.getUrlPath(match, originalPath, newCssPath);
            } else {
                // We need to rewrite the path, as any relative URLs will
                // not resolve correctly if Jawr has changed the CSS path.
                url = PathNormalizer.concatWebPath(originalPath, url);
                url = PathNormalizer.getRelativeWebPath(PathNormalizer.getParentPath(newCssPath), url);
                return "url(" + quoteStr + url + quoteStr + ")";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you need to configure Jawr to use this custom post processor in jawr.properties:

```
jawr.custom.postprocessors.customcsspathrewriter.class=com.bullethq.jawr.postprocessor.CustomCssUrlPathRewriterPostProcessor
jawr.css.bundle.factory.filepostprocessors=customcsspathrewriter
```

Comment: I feel very narcissistic answering my own question!

Comment: Hi,how to completely restrict processing images in jawr...?